# Stargazer: omit and omit.yes.no won't work

Tags: r, stargazer

I tried to use the `omit` and the `omit.yes.no` options in `stargazer()` to omit a dummy variable. It seems that there is a bug involving this option.
These are what I expect get from the output from stargazer.

```
                             logit_1       logit_2    logit_3

| covariates 1            |     21***   20 ***    21.4***
                             (0.2)     (0.12)    (0.10)

| covariate 2             |     0.5     0.3***     0.31***
                              (0.4)    (0.13)      (0.15)

| factor(covariate 3) A   |             0.123***   0.3***
                                        (0.06)     (0.08)

| factor(covariate 3) B   |             1.5**       1.03***
                                        (O.78)     (0.073)

|       OM                |    No         No        Yes
```

My stargazer command is the following;

```
stargazer (logit_1,logit_2,logit_3, omit='OM', omit.labels="OM", omit.yes.no = c("Yes","No")).
```

When I run the previous command the results of the OM variable is No Yes Yes.

When I run

```
stargazer (logit_1,logit_2, omit='OM', omit.labels="OM", omit.yes.no = c("Yes","No"))
```

I get No No.

And when I run

```
stargazer (logit_2,logit_3, omit='OM', omit.labels="OM", omit.yes.no = c("Yes","No"))
```

I get Yes Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug that will be removed in the next release. For now, you can apply the following fix:

On line 3956 of `stargazer-internal.R`, please replace:

```
if (!is.na(.global.coefficients[k,i])) {
```

by the following:

```
if (!is.na(.global.coefficients[.global.coefficient.variables[k],i]))
```

Then, install again from source. You can also e-mail the package's author for a working version of `stargazer` that corrects this issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the answer. Would it be possible to point out some references how to modify the file?

Comment: The source code is available on CRAN. Modify the code and install from CRAN.

Comment: @Marek, what does next release mean? To me it seems that the current version 5.1 was released on May 29, 2014 - nine days after this post. Can we assume that the bug is fixed?

Comment: Yes, bug fixed. See ChangeLog for each package release.